# how to change this string to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

SOLVED!:
The api had weird characters copied that were being sent over and breaking my javascript. always double check the values you are being sent!

To give full context on this:
to give the full context, i have a post api that is giving me the above structure in postman. i need to check the number and the code and if there are multiple objects returned. when i try to simply return the json i get the following error :json.parse()SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 2. Ive been trying to create work arounds to get the value but the best i can do is get it returned as a string using the code above. My goal is to check the code and the number of each object so i can validate against it. thank you for your help!

when returning my data from a post API I'm getting the response as a string. It's a formatted like an array of objects but I'm having difficulty parsing it due to the structure. the structure is as follows:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "number": 119777777,
            "code": "S",
            "name": "name Full award ",
            "year": 2021,
            "updatedate": "04-JAN-2023"
        },
        {
            "number": 119777777,
            "code": "H",
            "name": "Hospital funding.",
            "year": 2021,
            "updatedate": "04-JAN-2023"
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I transform this into something usable? I need to check the values of the code in each object for validation.

heres my code:

```
function GetFunding() {
    var responseClone; // 1
    fetch('my url',{
        method: "POST"
        
    })

    .then(function (response) {
        responseClone = response.clone(); // 2
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        // Do something with data
    }, function (rejectionReason) { // 3
        console.log('Error parsing JSON from response:', rejectionReason, responseClone); // 4
        responseClone.text() // 5
        .then(function (bodyText) {
          
            console.log('Received the following instead of valid JSON:', bodyText); // 6
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the exact issue? Because if you just want to convert the datatype from string to object you can just use JSON.parse(responseObject) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! when i try and parse it i keep getting errors: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Response]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at (index):1058:18

Comment: What are you trying to do with `responseClone`? More specifically `responseClone.text()` seems completely useless. `reponse.json()` is what you need and that is the `data` in the subsequent `.then()` handler.

Comment: Upon re-reading, it's totally unclear what the intention is. You're using `responseClone` in the rejection handler. Is the promise from `.json()` rejected? What is the reason given?

Comment: to give the full context, i have a post api that is giving me the above structure in postman. i need to check the number and the code and if there are multiple objects returned. when i try to simply return the json i get the following error :json.parse()SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 2. Ive been trying to create work arounds to get the value but the best i can do is get it returned as a string using the code above. My goal is to check the code and the number of each object so i can validate against it. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let fetchRes = fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    
    fetchRes.then(res =>
        res.json()).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
```

Your response is also correct but you can simplify using my code and for error handle you can write catch block.
You are saying that you are getting response in string but you should know that a object always have keys as a string , Even if you pass a number as a key to object , It will always go to string to object.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could work out:

```
   function GetFunding() {
        fetch('my url',{
            method: "POST"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const items = data.items;
            items.forEach(item => {
                if (item.code === 'S') {
                    // do something
                } else if (item.code === 'H') {
                    // do something else
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    };
```

Answer (score -4):

```js
const string = '{ "items": [ { "number": 119777777, "code": "S", "name": "name Full award ", "year": 2021, "updatedate": "04-JAN-2023" }, { "number": 119777777, "code": "H", "name": "Hospital funding.", "year": 2021, "updatedate": "04-JAN-2023" } ] }';
const obj = JSON.parse(string);
const arrayOfObjects = obj.items;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.